# Kubernetes service stays in pending state

Tags: service, kubernetes, status

Service showing pending status after exposing the deployment.

```
packet@ubuntu:/home/gss$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          22h
wms1         LoadBalancer   10.106.19.103   <pending>     8000:32461/TCP   17h
```

Installed kubeadm with one master and 4 worker nodes. 
created deployment with the command:

```
sudo docker run -p 8000:8000 w1
```

here w1 is my image name.

created service with the command:

```
kubectl expose deployment wms1 --type=LoadBalancer --port=8000
```

Comment: All nodes are in ready state. all pods are in running state.

Comment: Are you using any cloud provider? LoadBalancer is only supported by the cloud provider. You can try change the Type to the NodePort

Comment: I am using kubeadm in my local setup. I tried Nodeport also. EXternal-ip now showing <none>.

Comment: In case of NodePort external-ip will be <none>. You will be able to access it using your <machine IP>:<node_port>. Could you please describe your service which you installed using nodeport?

Comment: packet@ubuntu:/home/gss$ kubectl describe service wms1
Name:                     wms1
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=wms1
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=wms1
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.104.28.170
Port:                     <unset>  8000/TCP
TargetPort:               8000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31245/TCP
Endpoints:                172.244.1.3:8000,172.244.1.4:8000,172.244.1.5:8000 + 6 more...
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster

Comment: I tried to access with my ip. I am not able to access. I tried with https and http.

Comment: http://172.20.22.101:8000/    and https://172.20.22.101:8000/. Both are not reachable

Comment: Please paste following output in your questions edit:

kubectl describe svc <svc_name>

Nodeport is a port allocated between 30000,32767 and in your case it is 31245

Comment: packet@ubuntu:/home/gss$ kubectl describe svc wms1
Name:                     wms1
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=wms1
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=wms1
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.104.28.170
Port:                     <unset>  8000/TCP
TargetPort:               8000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31245/TCP
Endpoints:                172.244.1.3:8000,172.244.1.4:8000,172.244.1.5:8000 + 6 more...
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster

Comment: Kindly have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348677/kubernetes-cluster-is-not-exposing-external-ip-as-nodes/53348794#53348794

Comment: Got it, i need to access the service using the port given by nodeport(31245) but not the port i have given while i am creating the service(8000). I am able to access the service using <nod ip>:31245.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve external ip for your application in Kubernetes Cluster you have to use cloud provider like Google Kubernetes Engine or Amazon Web Services.

Please check:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#external-load-balancer-providers

Otherwise you can use Type NodePort and in that case Kubernetes master will allocate a port from a range specified by --service-node-port-range flag (default: 30000-32767), and each Node will proxy that port (the same port number on every Node) into your Service.

For detailed information: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

Answer (score 0):

In a second terminal, run the command:

```
minikube tunnel
```

restart your service and you should see the EXTERNAL-IP populated

Comment: This works, but if I wanted to have this running in the background, how do I accomplish that?

Comment: @nguni52 have you already tried this? minikube tunnel &> /dev/null &